# How to find trigonometric function from a list of points?

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, fourier-series

I am trying to find a way to model a trigonometric/other function to fit the points that can be found in the photograph. The aim is to turn this function into a polar equation to model the shape of an object.

Some people have recommended the use of Fourier Transform/Taylor approximations, but both require a function to begin with. The aim here is to find one function to model the entire curve, so while splitting it up into a piecewise function may be an intuitive way, I'm keeping it as a last resort.

[Image of points can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHazh.png)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform may be the procedure you are looking for.

Comment: Such fitting *always* involves specifying a class of candidate (basis) functions ahead of time.  *Always*.

Comment: [This Mathologer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qS4H6PEcCCA) goes into some detail into creating a fourier series that draws a picture. Also, [this post on the Mathematica board](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171755/how-can-i-draw-a-homer-with-epicycloids)